# Opcache "old scripts" not removed with opcache_reset()... a problem with some deployment tools. How to solve?

Tags: php, opcache

I'm using a **PHP deployment tool** which creates multiple "release" directories, with a `current` symlink pointing to the active (latest) release:

```txt
releases/
   /1
   /2
current -> releases/2
```

OPcache seems to **work fine with just one release**. I'm using a [preload script](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/main/symfony/framework-bundle/4.4/config/preload.php) from symfony framework:

```ini
opcache.preload = /var/www/vhosts/myproject/httpdocs/current/config/preload.php
```

The **problem begin after the second release**. In fact using `opcache_get_status()` I can see that all files from the previous release 1 are still present under "scripts" (despite calling `opcache_reset()` using curl):

```txt
["scripts"]=>
array(1542) {
  [0]=>
  string(72) "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/httpdocs/releases/1/vendor/autoload.php"
  [1]=>
  string(72) "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/httpdocs/releases/2/vendor/autoload.php"
```

And this is causing the following problem:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare composerRequiree7dcbbd7b36b37e14629ddf6c0ff22ac() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/myproject/httpdocs/releases/1/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:73) in /var/www/vhosts/myproject/httpdocs/releases/2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 73'

Removing the preload options solve the problem. But I'd like to understand why it's working this way and how to solve the issue leaving the preload enable.